# Add border if navbar hovers on choosen element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```js
export const NavBar = () => {
  return <div className="navbar">this is navbar</div>;
};

const Content = () => {
  return ( 
    <div className="main">
      <div className="background">
        some content
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar/>
      <Content/>
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.body);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;
}

.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100000;
}

.main {
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I'm trying to solve my problem and I don't know what to start with.
I created a simple codepen to display my problem:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/hisashin7331/pen/XWgPoWd)

So, I want to get my navbar to add black border, when it's over the "some content" element.
Is there any soltion that can help me? Or I should just set it for example:
When y scroll is between 247px and 453px change border. Something like this:

```
const [scroll, setScroll] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
    setScroll(window.pageYOffset)
}, [window.pageYOffset])

return <div style={{ borderBottom: `solid black ${(scroll >= 247 && scroll <= 453) && '2px'}` }}>navbar</div>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Do you want to add border to be separate nav-bar of which elements have same background-color with it?

Comment: @MohammadEsmaeilzadeh no, navbar and that div with content are separated React Elements, only ReactDOM connects them, Of course I can add id to both of them, if it can help :(

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried to create Stack Snippet but I get the script error all the time...

Comment: @DawidSzemborowski if your problem is just access to that element, I advise you to use `useRef()` instead directly using ID for it `https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref`

Answer (score 0):

with react you can use the onMouseEnter to check if the user hover on the element
first we will have state to save that info

```
const App = () => {
  const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar/>
      <Content/>
    </>
  );
}
```

and update it while the user hover the element

```
   <div className="main">
      <div className="background"
        onMouseEnter={() => setIsHover(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setIsHover(false)}>
        >
        some content
      </div>
    </div>
```

then change the className depend on the state.

```
export const NavBar = () => {
  return <div className={isHover? "navbar bordercss": "navbar"}>this isnavbar</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to compare **`background.getBoundingClientRect().top`** to **`navbar.getBoundingClientRect().bottom`**.
(If navbar is at the top of the document, you could also use `navbar.offsetHeight`.)

Here's how it might look with just vanilla JavaScript:

```js
const
  navbar = document.getElementById('navbar'),
  background = document.getElementById('background');
window.addEventListener("scroll", toggleNavbarBorder);

function toggleNavbarBorder(){
  const method = (background.getBoundingClientRect().top <= navbar.offsetHeight)
    ? "add"
    : "remove";
  navbar.classList[method]("bordered");
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
#navbar { width: 300px; height: 40px; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1; background: red; }
#main { width: 300px; height: 120vh; position: relative; background: blue; }
#background { width: 300px; height: 60px; position: absolute; top: 60px; background: red; }
.bordered{ border-bottom: 2px solid black; }
```

```html
<div id="navbar">navbar</div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="background">some content</div>
</div>
```